# Typing software that turns text into a test/game

Tags: windows, plain-text

The KeyHero website lets you input text and test yourself on typing:

https://www.keyhero.com/custom-typing-test/

I'm looking for something similar that turns the text more into a game like adds more colors and sound effects but basically, has you retype the text. Preferably reads each word aloud once you type each correctly.

Specifications:

- Windows 10
- Willing to spend 70$ish dollars on it
- What other info would be useful to answer this question?

Comment: Why not make typing a new olympic discipline? BTW, I am not joking :-)

Answer (score 2):

**Tux Typing**

It is mostly aimed at children, but still can be fun and educational for adults. It has plenty of colours and sound effects, though the graphics are fairly basic, and maybe a bit dated.

[image: Comet Zap]

It has two games, and a practice mode. It includes a number of word lists, on a variety of themes, or you can create custom word lists. Basically you have to type in the words as they appear on screen. But it does not read the words aloud.

[image: Fish Cascade]

It is free, and open source, under the GPL. It is available for Windows, Linux, or Mac OS X. It hasn't been updated for a while (since 2009), but should still work on most modern versions of Windows.

The offical website is at [Tux4kids - Tux Typing](http://tux4kids.alioth.debian.org/tuxtype/), but it seems the download links on there are not working.
It is available to download from [SourceForge - Tux Typing](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tuxtype/)

Answer (score 1):

There is a very old game [***Mario Teaches Typing***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Mario_educational_games#Mario_Teaches_Typing_games) by Interplay.

I learned to type using 2 hands and all fingers using this game but it was a long time ago :).

I'm not sure if you will be able to run it directly on Windows 10 but you can always run it on virtual machine using for example VirtualBox and FreeDOS.

You can play/download it for free on https://archive.org/details/msdos_Mario_Teaches_Typing_1992

There is also *Mario Teaches Typing 2* but I haven't played it.

Comment: I added a link where the game can be played. I don’t know that game, but it seems that you can’t add your own text, or can you?